# How to Create a Project Shell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to build an iOS based project that has basic features and can be used in the future as a base to create other apps (eg. has API functionality, Facebook login, etc.). Any ideas how I can set this up in XCode? Right now I'm having the problem where the project name, etc. stays the same from project to project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom project template. I should warn you that creating custom project templates in Xcode 4 is difficult and not documented well. The following article has more information on creating custom project templates:

[Creating Custom Xcode 4 Project Templates](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/12/creating-custom-xcode-4-project-templates/)